# How to use multiple accessor for registered widgets in PageObject?

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

[page-object gem](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object) automatically [generates multiple accessors](https://jkotests.wordpress.com/2013/06/24/defining-element-collections-using-the-page-objects-gem/comment-page-1/#comment-1563).

So for example you can use `links` in addition to `link`, like in example:

```
class MyPage
    include PageObject

    links(:tag_link, :css =>".tags-link a")
end
```

...

```
page.tag_link_elements.each do |link|
    puts link.text
end
```

**Question is, how to achieve the same "multiple accessors" feature for [custom registered widgets](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/wiki/Widgets-%28registering-custom-elements-with-PageObject%29) ?**

Answer (score 0):

The widget collection method becomes available to the page object when the widget is registered. Similar to the standard element collections, the collection method is the widget name with an "s" added to the end (though this can be overridden on a per widget basis). Note that this functionality was added in version 1.0.2 of the page-object gem (ie is fairly recent).

For example, let us assume the page HTML is the following:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="heading"><span>Title</span></div>
    <div class="item"><span>text1</span></div>
    <div class="item"><span>text2</span></div>
    <div class="item"><span>text3</span></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

We want to have a custom widget for the "item" divs. We can register a widget to define the items as:

```
class Item < PageObject::Elements::Div
  def description
    span_element.text
  end
end

PageObject.register_widget :item, Item, :div
```

Within the page class, `:item` will define the method for accessing a single widget. The pluralized name, `:items`, will define a collection of the widgets:

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  items(:item, class: 'item')
end
```

To use the widget collection, an `_elements` method is created (similar to that for standard collections). In this case, it would be called `item_elements`:

```
page = MyPage.new(browser)
p page.item_elements.length
#=> 3
p page.item_elements.map(&:description)
#=> ["text1", "text2", "text3"]
```

Comment: the multiple accessors for widgets feature was actually introduced in 1.0.3